# completeness of real and convergence of binary series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, complete-spaces

In page 'Completeness of the real numbers' of Wikipedia is said that: ''
completeness (of real) is equivalent to the statement that any infinite string of decimal digits is actually a decimal representation for some real number.''

I want formalize this idea: let $\mathbb{K}$ an ordered field.
For simplicity i considere binary representation instead decimal representation.
$\mathbb{K}$ has a natural metric structure ($d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$ as in $\mathbb{R}$) and is definited in particular the notion of series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$ where $a_n\in\{0,1\}$ forall $n$ ($2=1+1$ where $1$ is unit of $\mathbb{K}$).

Now if $\mathbb{K}$ is complete (i.e. Least-upper-bound property), then $\mathbb{K}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and over binary series converges.
I ask the converse: if every binary series is convergent, then $\mathbb{K}$ is complete?

I must assume that $\mathbb{K}$ is archimedean field?

Comment: If every binary series is convergent, then $\Bbb K$ is an extension field of $\Bbb R$. If we assume $\Bbb K$ is not archimedean, then there is some $q > \Bbb N$, and therefore $\epsilon = q^{-1} < \frac 1n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. But then if $a_n$ is not eventually $0$, for any upper bound $r$ for the partial sums, we must also have that the partial sum is less than $r - \epsilon$, so it would be impossible for $r$ to be the limit of the sum.